# How to check if something is being returned as a string or a date as string?

Tags: string, swift3

In my app the api can return strings or dates as strings. I need to check if the api returns a date first. if it is not a date, just populate the field with the string. If it is a date, do the conversion before populating the field. The conversion and the populate the field part I have figured out, but how can I tell if it's returning a date as a string or a string? This is what the api returns:

```
data?.data?.nextAvailability
```

So I need it be something like

```
if data?.data?.nextAvailability is a string { 
    // do something 
} else if data?.data?.nextAvailability is a date as a string {
    // do this 
}
```

Comment: To be clear, it is returning a string no matter what, just the formatting can change?

Comment: yes returning a string no matter what

Comment: for instance it will either return a string that says something like  "chose one" or if it's a date "2017-06-09T15:30:00.000Z". I'm then converting the date string to say "June 9, 11:30 am"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could maybe do something like this:

```
let string = data?.data?.nextAvailability

let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ"

guard let date = dateFormatter.date(from: string) else {
        print("not a date") // And do what you need to do
        return
    }
// is a date... do what you need to do with a date.
print(date)
```

Comment: but I'm not sure what the string will be to put in the let string = "2017-06-09T15:30:00.000Z" area. it's being returned form the api as "data?.data?.nextAvailability"

Comment: Just plug that string that you get in. Updated answer.

Comment: I had to switch a few things around but this did the trick, thanks!